# DB2 Convert milliseconds to timestamp

Tags: sql, db2

In DB2 I’m trying to convert the number of milliseconds since 01/01/1970 (epoch time), into a suitable date format.

So far I have got this query (where MILLI is 1417493940000, the number of milliseconds) ;

```
SELECT to_char(TIMESTAMP ('1970-01-01-00.00.00.00000') + (MILLI/1000) SECOND) 
FROM MYTABLE
```

And it returns, which is ok-ish ;
Dec 2, 2014 4:19:00 AM

I want the format to be more like this – ‘02-12-2014 04:19:00’

Any ideas if this is possible ?

Comment: Epoch is usually in UTC; don't you need to account for the local timezone? In some DB2 versions the `TO_CHAR()` function, and its equivalent `TIMESTAMP_FORMAT()`, has the second argument: the format specifier. Check the manual for your DB2 version.

Answer (score 4):

Think I've got it now - this query seems to do the job nicely ;

```
SELECT VARCHAR(VARCHAR_FORMAT((TIMESTAMP ('1970-01-01-00.00.00.00000') + (MILLI/1000) SECOND), 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 20 ) 
FROM MYTABLE
```

And gives this:

```
02-12-2014 04:19:00
```

Comment: Note that the result is in UTC. You have to add `CURRENT TIMEZONE` to the result to adjust for local time.